# connection between Java backend computations and GUI

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I wanted to ask you a question about connecting Java and JavaScript codes.  Now I have Java backend computation code, which works right, and I also have GUI (html and javascript), but I do not know how to connect them. I need to show the results of Java computations in GUI (just to change the text field value for the result of Java computations) and send the user input to Java bakend.
I read a lot of stuff in Internet, but I am still not sure how to deal with it. I read some information about Maven and Tomcat apaches, but I am still not sure what they actually are and if I should use them.

Comment: maybe websockets, if it is ok about your browser support requirements

Comment: I voted to close your post, since it's too broad to be answered (in terms of code). However, I would like to give you a direction. You could expose an API to your client. I mean a REST API with a couple of methods, that would internally call the Java computations you refer to and would return as a result to the client that you want. Then you could consume this API making Ajax calls to it. This is a starting point for doing some googling based on these terms. Then you can come back and ask as many focused questions as you want, that they could be answered. I hope that helps :)